# How to get selected values in bootstrap dropdown in angular

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 5 dropdown in angular.I want to console.log the selected option

```
<div class="dropdown">

  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">

    Dropdown button

  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">

    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>

    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>

    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

want to get the selected option and display it as the button name.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example using a reactive form where you have two alternatives where you can update the text on the dropdown button (see the comments in the code). Please note: In the HTML I had to add a hidden input-field, where the selected value can be stored.

First the **Typescript-Part**:

```
constructor() {

    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
        dropdown: new FormControl(this.dropdownBtnText)
    });

    // Alternative 1:
    // You can subscribe to the changes in the dropdown and update 'dropdownBtnText' here:

    this.formGroup.get('dropdown')?.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        console.error('Selected value: ', value);
        this.dropdownBtnText = value;
    });
}

select(value: string) {
    console.log('Selected value: ', value);
    this.formGroup.get('dropdown')?.setValue(value);

    // Alternative 2:
    // You can update 'dropdownBtnText' here:

    this.dropdownBtnText = value;
}
```

Then the **HTML-Part**:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <input type="hidden" formControlName="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">  
            {{ dropdownBtnText }}  
        </button>
  
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="select('action')">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="select('another_action')">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="select('something_else')">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are using click event and passing the string but what if number of dropdown options are more and coming dynamically from database